# Reading a dictionary in a file that has values as lists

Tags: python, dictionary

How do I 'unpack' a dictionary from a text file with values as lists? I've used this code I have found on the internet:

```
with open("save.txt") as f:
      for line in f:
        ( key, val) = line.split()
        d[int(key)] = val
```

but it gives me this error

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

save.txt

```
pop ['7', '8', '4', '8']
funk ['9', '2', '0', '2']
pop ['7', '8', '4', '8']
funk ['9', '2', '0', '2']
stack ['9', '0', '3', '0']
```

Comment: Could you give some samples of your `save.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some few problems with your initial code

1. Your save.txt file is weird, because all the `keys` are the same if you will convert this file into a dictionary, the last one with key `test` is the only one that will be the final result of the iteration.
2. `d[int(key)] = val` the expected key here is a string which is `test` so `int(key)` is pointless and will result into a ValueError.
3. `( key, val) = line.split()` You are splitting without specifying a delimiter so you are receiving the error `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` because split is trying to use all delimiter like spaces, coma...
4. Again here `d[int(key)] = val` the `val` here is still a string and not a list

Here's a sample code that will work on your requirement

Your `save.txt`

```
test1 ['0', '0', '0', '0']
test2 ['0', '0', '0', '0']
test3 ['1', '0', '1', '0']
```

Your python code

```
import ast

d = {}
with open("save.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.split(maxsplit=1)
        d[key] = ast.literal_eval(val)

print(d)
```

Here is some explanation,

`(key, val) = line.split(maxsplit=1)`
we only want to split the first `space` that is the reason of maxsplit here, you can also do it like
`(key, val) = line.split(' ', maxsplit=1)`

to explicitly say that you want to split only the first space.

`import ast`
and
`d[key] = ast.literal_eval(val)`

AST is a python package that you can use to evaluate a literal and convert it into a list. You can learn more about this here [AST Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html)

Here's my output of this code

`{'test1': ['0', '0', '0', '0'], 'test2': ['0', '0', '0', '0'], 'test3': ['1', '0', '1', '0']}`

Answer (score 1):

You should split a line into two parts and then convert the second part into a list with `literal_eval()`:

```
import ast
d = {}
with open("save.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        key, val = line.split(' ', 1)
        d[key] = ast.literal_eval(val)
```

For your reference, there will be only one entry in the dictionary constructed from your file, because all three keys are identical.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is better than use `eval` directly.

Answer (score -1):

Warning: this is a simple and quick way to solve your problem. But it may be dangerous if you are not sure if there is some dangerous code in the file.

```
with open("save.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.split(' ', 1)
        d[key] = eval(val)
```

Comment: For example, the `save.txt` is create by the user. And the data is exported from an experimental instrument. All the line is in the format of `text ['0', '1', '2']`. The questioner only will use it one time. In this case, the questioner can use eval to solve the problem within 1 minute.

Comment: So I add the warning in the first line. Different people have different needs, everyone should take a look at his own situation and choose the best one.

Comment: One should not suggest an unsafe solution if there are safe solutions. So, no, I do not buy your logic.

Answer (score -1):

The code snippet you supplied works if your file in formatted as follows:

```
key1 value1
key2 value2
key3 value3
```

`for line in f:` will go through the file line by line, so `line` will first contain the string `"key1 value1"`

`line.split()` by default spilits on a space (`" "`), so when this is executed on `line`, it results in an array like so: `["key1", "value1"]`

To use Python's unpacking, the number of variables needs to match. The error you are getting (`ValueError`) explains that "too many values to unpack". As you are splitting on a `" "`, I suspect that you have more than one space per line, which yields more variables to unpack.

The contents of `save.txt` would be useful to further assist you.

Answer (score -1):

```
with open("save.txt") as f:
    d = {}
    for line in f:
        (key, *vallist) = line.split()
        d[key] = vallist
```

Key in records is string, can not be typecasted to int.